# Make tomcat unload compiled JSP files from metaspace

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

Similar to [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ( PermGen space) and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at the opening the jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975567/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-and-java-lang-classnotfoundexception) but with slightly more modern problems.

I have a legacy app which has a lot of JSPs.  Some of them use `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...` to do the spaces (as a CSS cleanup on the page wasn't done yet).

Recently we've been getting out of memory errors after the system has been running for a while.  I was evaluating the heap space and it seems under control, forcing periodic GCs show that it is less than 100MBs of heap, but the non-heap size is increasing.  I have capped the size to 300MBs which seems like a lot already as the system generally runs at 512MB in Docker.

Anyway, I use JSPC and when I totalled the amount of bytes all the generated class files take up I get *21,981,012 bytes.* which I take it goes into metaspace based on other answers I have seen.  Of course that number is likely increased by a large portion as it is unpacked into memory.

So my question is, is there a way to configure Java or Tomcat to release class data from metaspace when it is not in use and reload it later if needed?

UPDATE: I explicitly limited the metaspace size in my `CATALINA_OPTS` so that it will fail faster -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=200m -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=100m

Here is the VisualVM.  The classes do not seem to get unloaded and the metaspace does not go down either.
[image]

And here is the Metaspace.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JVM, by default, handles the loading and unloading of the classes. What is your application command line? Are you seeing OOM: Metaspace or JavaHeap?