# how to make tomcat explode the war files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

With reference to [tomcat and extracted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945820/tomcat-and-extracted-files/14965275#14965275) 
I have configured server.xml to `auto deploy : true`. 
My war file name is ROOT.war as I do not want /subdir after the site.com.

But I dont see the .css .js .java or .class files in /webappts/ROOT or any where. (I have them in the ROOT.war and the site is running fine with reflecting them)

I only see .class and .java in

```
/var/cache/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/_/org/apache/jsp/

/var/cache/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/classes/
```

how to configure tomcat to explode the .war file?

**Update I**

I have `Host name="localhost" appBase="/home/ubuntu/www" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"` 
and I still dont see unpacking . My ROOT.war is in /home/ubuntu/www

**Update II**

One problem I see is that:

```
Feb 27, 2013 6:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/ubuntu/www/ROOT.war
Feb 27, 2013 6:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/home/ubuntu/www/ROOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
```

If i **manually** make ROOT in /home/ubuntu/www/ **with chmod 777** . it gives **404** error (doesnt exists)

Comment: Are the .css, and .js files actually in the WAR file? (the .java files you shouldn't see there...)

Comment: @ppeterka yes they are

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, but is the server running? I noticed with our setup if you place the war file in the directory and start the server it expands (I may be way off base here).

Comment: @onaclov2000  see update 2 please

Comment: @ppeterka  see update 1 and 2 please

Comment: The windows version I used, seemed to unpack automatically, haven't used linux version.

Comment: What are permissions, owner and group of /home/ubuntu/www ?

Comment: @rootkit drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Feb 27 16:11 www . I made it 777 and now ROOT folder is created and populated. WORKS. You may answer this as an "answer" thanks but 
  making www as chmod 777 is a security risk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `/home/ubuntu/www` folder needs to be writable by Tomcat process. The owner and group should be `tomcat6/tomcat7` (depending on which TC you use). Like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 tomcat7 tomcat7 4096 Feb 27 14:08 webapps
```

You shouldn't `chmod 777` the folder, this is a security risk as you correctly surmised. `chown tomcat7:tomcat7` should work.

Comment: Awesome!  This solved my problem.  One note, I'm using Tomcat 7 and had to use:  sudo chown tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `unpackWARs==true` is set.

> Set to true if you want web applications that are placed in the
>   appBase directory as web application archive (WAR) files to be
>   unpacked into a corresponding disk directory structure, false to run
>   such web applications directly from a WAR file. WAR files located
>   outside of the Host's appBase will not be expanded.

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation