# WAR file deployment to Tomcat fails: URI scheme error

Tags: java, jersey, war, tomcat8, url-scheme

I have a war file that was built with Maven and it contains all the dependencies it needs (it's a REST service). 
I am using Java JRE 1.8.0_152, and Tomcat 8.5.24 on both machines. One is a Windows 10 64bit machine, the other a Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit machine. I have built (in Eclipse/Maven) and deployed the war file successfully on the Windows 10 machine, but when I deploy the same war file on the Windows server machine, I get the following error on Tomcat startup (or war file deployment):

```
13-Dec-2017 14:41:36.603 SEVERE [bla.bla-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: The URI scheme war of the URI war:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/bla.war*/WEB-INF/classes/bla/bla/ is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs.
Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application
```

And then, a further message that I think is relevant:

```
13-Dec-2017 14:41:36.615 SEVERE [bla.bla-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/bla] threw load() exception
```

I am using Jersey for the REST stuff, *but both machines have identical versions of the JRE and Tomcat installed, and it's the same war file !* (I have even wiped the Tomcat installations and installed from scratch - same thing).

I'm not even sure where to start looking, since all dependencies are contained in the war file (including the jersey jars) and it IS working on the Windows 10 machine; the only thing I find noteworthy is the asterisk in the error message after the war file name ("bla.war*"). I'm not sure where that comes from, or if it's indeed relevant to the root cause of the error.

Any hints/ideas ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Dunno, but it looks like different tomcat configurations. Is the Tomcat configuration on the server set to unpack the war? E.g. You need to ensure that unpackWARs==true is set.

Comment: @Karl Nicholas: thanks, I'll check. I don't think there is a difference since both are "download, unpack, run"-type installations of Tomcat - but it's something !

Comment: @KarlNicholas: good lord - it WAS the unpackWAR setting ! I had forgotten that I had created two <host> entries for testing purposes... How can we turn your comment into an answer ? You deserve the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file is telling you that Tomcat/the JVM is attempting to read the files directly out of the .war file. `URI war:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.24/webapps/bla.war*/WEB-INF/classes/bla/bla/` is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs. `Try using a different deployment mechanism` such as explicitly declaring root resource and provide

So, it looks like different tomcat configurations. Is the Tomcat configuration on the server set to unpack the war? E.g. You need to ensure that `unpackWARs==true` is set. Reference: [how to make tomcat explode the war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113700/how-to-make-tomcat-explode-the-war-files)

Comment: Karl, it was exactly that. Because the "server" is on the internet, I played around with some settings, amongst which were two host sections - one of which had unpackWARs=false. Tiny detail, big impact. :-)

Comment: I want to deploy the war in unexploded mode and facing similar problem. Any solutions for this yes in tomcat